# Hibernate map repeated column (within an entity)

Tags: java, hibernate

Table looks like this: I am skipping few columns for simplicity

```
ColumnnID   ColumnA    ColumnB
     1         1           A
     2         1           B
     3         2           C
     4         3           C
```

Table mapped to an entity MyClass

```
class MyClass {

  @Id
  private long columnId;

  @column(name = "columnA")
  private long columnA;

  @column(name = "columnB")
  private long columnB;
}
```

After executing simple query (criteria) I wont my hibernate entity look like this

```
Criteria criteria = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(MyClass.class);
```

and result:

```
data: {
    myClass : {
        columnId: 1
        columnA: 1
        mapColumnB : [
           A,
           B    
        ],
     },
      myClass : {
        columnId: 3
        columnA: 2
        mapColumnB : [
           C   
        ],
     },
     myClass : {
        columnId: 4
        columnA: 3
        mapColumnB : [
           C    
        ],
     }

    }
```

Any ideas? need to map within an entity.

If I can do it and can get only row by row, what would be efficient way in Java to rebuild list to presentation I need ?

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT*:** the answer is for original question (before editing the question by post owner(asker)!!) and it's not for current version of question!!!.

---

The expected result you mentioned, **isn't** an **Entity**, it just could be a result of a *`criteria`* or *`hql`* query.

You can write the *Entity* according to your *data / table / query* but you need to provide an `Id` for the Entity(mapped from unique field(s)), and as your sample data does not have a *unique* column(s) so you can't, you have to add an extra column(*PK / Unique*) to the table or you have to use a *Composite* key for the `Id`, I mean use a combination of `(ColumnA and ColumnB)` for `Id`, just do a little search you'll see how to do it; as soon as you did it you'll be able to get the expected result without any complicated *criteria* or *hql* query.